# understanding selection, iteration, arrays, counting, etc. I know the concepts behind these terms, but don't know how to use them

Tags: pseudocode

I am a student and I am taking the computer science IGCSE course in my school. I am confident with the theory paper and also confident in most parts of the programming paper except for parts where I am required to write pseudocode for a given program. I searched for tutorials, and continued to search for some questions I have. I am having problem trying to use these terms stated in actual pseudocode and don't get the overall structure of them. I figured that stack overflow would be a great website for me to get different answers from people. I am eager to learn pseudocode and wish to understand the very basics of the structure if anyone is willing to explain it.

thanks for your time,
really appreciate it!

Comment: _I figured that stack overflow would be a great website for me to get different answers from people..._ Yes, but first of all you should be taking [this tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Comment: Stack Overflow certainly can be a great resource for help with programming, and you are invited to learn more about this community here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour  Unfortunately, what you're currently asking is simply too broad to be answered in this format.  You're essentially asking us to teach you programming logic.  We don't really offer tutoring services like this.  There's nothing special about "pseudocode", it's just logic expressed in no particular language syntax.  If you can logically describe a process, then you've written pseudocode.